# Torque on a rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, torque

This is a question that has bothered me for a long time and I haven't found an answer to anywhere. Imagine you have a steel rod balanced on a fulcrum, but not evenly balanced as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Now naturally the rod would tip over because of the uneven weight distribution but my question is what would be the net torque that is pulling the rod to the ground. Since this particular question is just one I came up with myself, I'm looking for an explanation rather than an answer. I believe this has something to do with net torque= Inertia x Angular acceleration, but I keep coming to dead ends. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the question you asked earlier was misunderstood as a homework question and that you seek an explanation not an answer. Firstly, the statement "Balanced on a Fulcrum but not Evenly Balanced" does not make sense, you meant to say the rod is put on a fulcrum but is not in equilibrium. In the diagram you have linked with your question, the total length of rod is 40 m, and it have its fulcrum at the 20 m point. I dont know from where you got these measurements (again I smell a homework question) but anyways, assuming the weight of rod to be evenly distributed throughout. Assuming the total weight of the rod to be **x newton.** then it would be **x/2 newton** on either side of its midpoint i.e. in this case 20 m mark. Since, you have given total length of rod as 40, and you have shown the rod is balanced on a fulcrum at its 20cm mark. So the rod will perfectly remain in equilibrium since weight on both the sides would be equal, therefore either your question is mistaken or the given figure has no use.

Now coming back to explanation, in order to calculate the net torque, you have to take the algebraic sum of both the moment of forces on acting on either side, i.e. clockwise and anticlockwise. In order to do this, it is conventionally stated that the clockwise moment of force is given a minus sign (-) before it and anticlockwise moment of force is given a plus sign (+). So that on the algebraic sum of both these moments we get the net torque with either a plus sign before it or a minus sign, if we get the answer with a plus sign then the net torque is anticlockwise as stated, if we get a minus sign then the net torque is clockwise.

Like in your given diagram, the weight of rod on right side of fulcrum is causing clockwise rotation let us say **- 40 Nm** (note the minus sign given before, which is depicting clockwise rotation) and the weight of rod on left side of fulcrum is causing anticlockwise rotation which is **+40 Nm** (plus sign depicting anticlockwise rotation) Now in order to calculate net torque we would take the algebraic sum :-

**+40 Nm - 40Nm = 0**

Hence, we conclude the net torque to be zero. I hope you got the explanation you desired.

Comment: Again, please don't answer off-topic questions, especially ones that have been reposted =)

Comment: i apologise for that, but since the earlier question of the OP was misunderstood as a homework exercise, and although it was a homework question, the OP seems new to SE and did not realise to edit the existing question to receive an explanation not an answer.